# Splitting column with XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, split

I have a SQL column named "details" and it contains the following data:

```
<changes><RoundID><new>8394</new></RoundID><RoundLeg><new>JAYS CLOSE AL6 Odds(1 - 5)</new></RoundLeg><SortType><new>1</new></SortType><SortOrder><new>230</new></SortOrder><StartDate><new>01/01/2009</new></StartDate><EndDate><new>01/01/2021</new></EndDate><RoundLegTypeID><new>1</new></RoundLegTypeID></changes> 
<changes><RoundID><new>8404</new></RoundID><RoundLeg><new>HOLLY AREA AL6 (1 - 9)</new></RoundLeg><SortType><new>1</new></SortType><SortOrder><new>730</new></SortOrder><StartDate><new>01/01/2009</new></StartDate><EndDate><new>01/01/2021</new></EndDate><RoundLegTypeID><new>1</new></RoundLegTypeID></changes>
<changes><RoundID><new>8379</new></RoundID><RoundLeg><new>PRI PARK AL6 (1 - 42)</new></RoundLeg><SortType><new>1</new></SortType><SortOrder><new>300</new></SortOrder><StartDate><new>01/01/2009</new></StartDate><EndDate><new>01/01/2021</new></EndDate><RoundLegTypeID><new>1</new></RoundLegTypeID></changes>
```

What is the easiest way to separate this data out into individual columns? (that is all one column)

Comment: SQL Server? Oracle? My SQL? Others?

Comment: SQL Server IS what im using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATA.query('/changes/RoundID/new/text()')  AS RoundID
      ,DATA.query('/changes/RoundLeg/new/text()') AS RoundLeg
      ,DATA.query('/changes/SortType/new/text()') AS SortType
      -- And so on and so forth
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(XML, Details) AS DATA
      FROM YourTable) AS T
```

Comment: Hi That is great but it is still keeping the new either side, For instance: <new>892</new> for round id and <new>NAYLORROAD S13 </new>, do you know how i can remove the new

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your result set from the sql (mysql or whatever) you will probably have an array of strings. As I understand your question, you wanted to know how to extract each of the xml nodes that were contained in the string that was stored in the column in question. You could loop through the results from the sql query and extract the data that you want. In php it would look like this:

```
// Set a counter variable for the first dimension of the array, this will 
// number the result sets. So for each row in the table you will have a
// number identifier in the corresponding array.
$i = 0;
$output = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
    // Here use simpleXML to extract the node data, just by using the names of the 
    // XML Nodes, and give it the same name in the array's second dimension.
    $output[$i]['RoundID'] =  $xml->RoundID->new;
    $output[$i]['RoudLeg'] = $xml->RoundLeg->new;
    // Simply create more array items here for each of the elements you want 
    $i++;
}

foreach ($output as $out) {
    // Step through the created array do what you like with it.
    echo $out['RoundID']."\n";
    var_dump($out);
}
```